# Split a list in R into new vectors

Tags: r

My question looks quite simple but I can't get my head around it.

I have a list:

```
f <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = c('x','y','z'), c = c(0.1,0.2,0.3))
```

I want to split this list such that I get three new vectors in my environment where:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c('x','y','z')
c <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
```

So that when I do `print(a)` I should get `c(1,2,3)` as its value and so on.

Comment: `with(f, print(a))` It is better to have the elements in the list. It is not a good idea to construct a bunch of objects from the list.

Comment: why is this question downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `attach(f)`. But remember to do `detach` later.

Comment: `library("fortunes"); fortune(379)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be

```
for (i in names(f)) {
  assign(i, f[[i]])
}
```

Your original list will still exist in the environment. You may or may not want to remove it.

Comment: `library("fortunes"); fortune(236)`

Comment: @jogo - 1. I FULLY agree that it is usually not reasonable to split a list into its parts (can we exclusively say that it is NEVER reasonable?) 2. We should probably ask for removing `assign` from base R ;-).

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is the best way:

```
list2env(f,.GlobalEnv)
```